# Valuing a warrant on a warrant

Tags: options, valuation

How would you go about valuing a European warrant that entitles you to a) 1 share of a company and 2) 1 warrant on that same company?

Comment: Welcome to quant.SE and thanks for asking your question here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are essentially dealing with two options:

$EU\,{Warrant}(S_t) = BlackScholesCall(S_t)+CompoundCall(S_t)$

The Black-Scholes formula is known, and Compound Option pricing has various approaches in research which you may find.